# behaviour of sequence of bounded real functions $f_n$ converging uniformly to $f$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I've been going at a statement trying to prove it or find a counterexample:

$f_n : R\rightarrow R$ is a sequence of bounded functions converging uniformly to $f: R \rightarrow R$. If each function $f_n$ has a limit at infinity, then $f$ has a limit at infinity.

I'm pretty sure the statement is true because since $f_n$ is converging uniformly to $f$ then every behaviour from $f_n$ should be in $f$ but not sure how to prove that. Any hints or am I totally wrong to assume that?

Comment: Write out a proof by showing that the limits if $f_n$'s form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so that if the sequence $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy then it converges uniformly to $f$ and therefore also has a limit at $\infty$ ?